# Need help in extracting a expression from a log using regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a log as a string, and I am trying to capture the error message from it. the regex I tried did not work.

> String = "Retrying for error: [[\"billing\",\{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid payment email
>   provided']}\"]]"

I need to extract the error message which is

> Invalid payment email provided

How I can extract this, using regex?

I tried the pattern `Retrying for error: (\\.+)`, but it doesn't work:

```
String pattern = "Retrying for error: (\\.+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(unescapedStr);
if (m.find()) {
  error = m.group(1);
}
```

How can I get the expected result?

> Invalid payment email provided, Actual: null

Comment: Try `"Retrying for error:.*\\[u'([^']+)"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dtg29v/1).

Comment: why did you put double slash in front of `.`?

Comment: That String can't even compile. You have an invalid escape sequence ``\\\``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I got the following result:
`Retrying for error: [[\"billing\",\\\{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid payment email provided`
Is there any way I can get `Invalid payment email provided.` as the result?

Comment: You get `Invalid payment email provided.` [with my pattern](https://ideone.com/hXo14b)

Comment: Oh Yes. I was using group(0). Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to use regex. how about this

```
        String x = "Retrying for error: [[\"billing\",\\{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid payment email provided']}\"]]";

        String c = x.replace("Retrying for error: ","");

        String g = c.substring(c.lastIndexOf('[')+1);

        String v = g.substring(0, g.indexOf(']'));

        System.out.println(v);
```

this prints

`u'Invalid payment email provided'`

now do your logs have multiple instances of `Retrying for error:`? also, does this

`"Retrying for error: [[\"billing\",\\{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid payment email provided']}\"]]";`

represent a single line in your logs?

The main idea is this:
If each line in your log file has just one instance of `Retrying for error:`, then you can easily parse the log one line at a time and iteratively strip away stuff that you dont need.

Comment: The expression `Retrying for error:` occurs only once in the log, however, this is not a single line. There are other lines to after this. Also, the stuff in the logs is not constant, it will change based on the scenario.

Comment: hmm, ok. but will `Retrying for error:` always occur? even if the other stuff changes in the log? If so, the above approach will still work. by the way, how big are the logs?

Comment: Yes, the `Retrying fir error:` will always occur. I can test the code for multiple scenarios. I hope this works in all. Thanks!

Comment: sure, good luck. also, please share a snippet on how you are reading the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex:

```
Retrying for error:.*\[u'([^']+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dtg29v/2).

**Details**

- `Retrying for error:` - a literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\[u'` - a `[u'` substring
- `([^']+)` - Capturing group #1 (`matcher.group(1)` value): 1+ chars other than `'`.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/hXo14b):

```
String unescapedStr = "Retrying for error: [[\"billing\",\\{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid payment email provided']}\"]]";
String pattern = "Retrying for error:.*\\[u'([^']+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(unescapedStr);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
// => Invalid payment email provided
```